# Video keeps saving single frame

Tags: video, node-editor

I have been trying to figure out the video making in blender. I have a green screen and decided to film myself in front of it. I uploaded the video into blender in the compositing category. Once I filled my green screen in with a background I was ready to save the video I have created. I Have the file format as an xvid but it still only saves the single frame of the video I am paused on. Yes, I am new to blender. Any attempt of help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about exporting, you'll have to press the "animation" button.

[image: proprieties window]

Comment: Thanks for helping. I did press the animation button, however I didn't even think about exporting it. That helped me save the video to my computer, but I have another problem. I try to play it in Windows Media player but it is a DAE file extension. What could I export it with so its just a video I could watch or upload to youtube with?

Comment: Whoops never mind. I figured it out! Thanks for the help!